# Can we attach WinAppDriver with Selenium WebDriver (Automating Siebel/Silverlight application)?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, winappdriver

I am opening **Internet Explorer (ixplore.exe) using WinAppDriver** and navigating to a URL by first finding the locator of address bar using **inspect.exe** and then hitting the enter. It navigates me to the page successfully.Now what i want from here is i can use selenium WebDriver along with WinAppDriver so that I can handle both Web as well as Desktop elements.
I am trying to automate **Silverlight/Siebel** application.

Here is my code sample for opening IE browser using Windows Appium driver:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", Platform.WIN10);
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "WindowsPC");
    capabilities.setCapability("app", "C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe");

    try {
        // winDriver = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new
        // URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), capabilities);
        winDriver = new WindowsDriver<RemoteWebElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), capabilities);
        winDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        winDriver.manage().window().maximize();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception occurred while initiating driver :" + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use WinAppDriver alongside Selinium.
You will need to create and manage both drivers separately. It will be important to distinguish between the two drivers. i.e you won't be able to inspect the DOM from your WinAppDriver, and you won't be able to interact with the desktop from Selenium.

#### However

If all you are using WinAppDriver for is to start Internet Explorer and navigate to the page under test, you can use Selenium to start IE and navigate, allowing you to remove your dependency on WinAppDriver.